# Twitch error #6000

Tags: 18.04, firefox, file-format, mp4, h264

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu and logged into Firefox. I got my usual addons and credentials and after some time logged into twitch to find that every stream gets the following error:

[image]

I tried disabling add-ons like uBlock Origin, Privacy badger, Decentraleyes, NoScript, HTTPS Everywhere. All of these are currently disabled.

I tried disabling and enabling javascript. Didn't work. I tried looking solutions, couldn't find anything constructive. Everything else works fine on twitch. The chat is moving and everything, except the actual video stream. Never got this error on other OS (Windows). Any help would be golden.

***Update:*** The problem extended to several youtube videos as well. Check the below screenshot for unsupported file formats:
[image]

Tried multiple other solutions provided online to enable these file formats with no luck. Completely revamped `about:config` hoping it would solve the problem, it didn't.

Tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Restarted browser and system. No change.
**Tried chrome** and everything works fine over there. It hurts my soul to use chrome for this stupid issue, when the original reason I installed Ubuntu was to get rid of proprietary software.

I was using Firefox on Windows with no issue like these. This really discourages me to keep using open source systems.

Comment: If you Google "Twitch error 6000" you get some possibly helpful results, like [this Reddit thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/Twitch/comments/9jrgki/twitch_machine_unplugged_error_code_6000/) that points to XLR scripts being blocked (though I don't know what that means personally).

Comment: Tried the same thread results. No luck @wjandrea

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution on another forum, posting it here because this is higher on the search engine results:

Install the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. It, or at least something that this metapackage installs, contains the codec Twitch wants. Works for a fresh Ubuntu install. Unfortunately for OP this does contain proprietary stuff hence the package name. But... h.264 is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just install codecs in software manager
There is tab called Extensions, than check Codecs tab.
Some of them will fix your problem